# What is the name of the executable that launches the Unity app drawer / menu?

Tags: command-line, unity

I would like to run

```
xpra start :100 --start-child=
```

Now, I could just run 'xterm', but it would be far better if I could run the Unity app drawer or "start menu" or something similar which could graphically display icons and launch things like Firefox, Terminal, etc with a click. What is the name of the executable I can pass that will present a graphical menu?

Comment: Has this `xpra` graphical interface?

Comment: Not by itself, no. XPRA allows for remote GUI access, like RDP or VNC. It needs something else to provide the actual desktop environment.